# PHP: Adding an element in array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to add a new index to an array and add values to it in a loop.

for example i've following array in a loop

```
[books] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [book_id] => 1
                    [date_issue] => 2016-07-24 00:00:00
                    [date_return] => 2016-07-25 00:00:00
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [book_id] => 2
                    [date_issue] => 2016-07-24 00:00:00
                    [date_return] => 2016-07-25 00:00:00
                )

        )
```

This is how i am getting it

```
  foreach ($query_books->result() as $key => $value) {
     $result['books']= $query_books->result();
 }
 print_r($result);
```

now in each iteration i want  to add a new index after `[date_return]` how do  i do that please help

Comment: this solves your problem may be http://stackoverflow.com/a/38709442/4595675

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add data dynamically to an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325009/add-data-dynamically-to-an-array)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 no the accepted answer was the proper solution in loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your `foreach` loop doesn't look like it really needs to be a loop. You aren't doing anything with `$key` or `$value`; it's really just overwriting `$result['books']` repeatedly with the result of `$query_books->result()`. You should get the same result with just:

```
$result['books'] = $query_books->result();
```

After you have that, you can loop over it and add new information:

```
foreach ($result['books'] as $book) {
    $book->new_index = 'new value';
}
print_r($result);
```

The items in `$result['books']` are not actually arrays; they are stdClass Objects. This is why object syntax (`$book->new_index`) is used to add the property rather than array syntax (`$book['new_index']`).

---

Theoretically, if you *did* have an array of arrays, it would be necessary to use a reference (`&$book` rather than `$book`) in your `foreach` loop in order to modify them, because `foreach` creates a copy of each item as it iterates:

```
foreach ($result['books'] as &$book) {   // use a reference
    $book['new_index'] = 'new value';
}
unset($book); // unset the reference

print_r($result);
```

It is *not* necessary to use a reference to modify an array of objects like you have, because the copy of the object identifier in the `foreach` loop still points to the same object. You can read about this in more detail in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

Comment: hi can you please explain this a bit  i really dont get this usage of reference and object operator in this  scenario , Thanks

Comment: if its sub elements are objects, no need for `&` its already represents references to the same object, it should work without it

Comment: @Ghost yeah, I wrote the answer originally mistakenly thinking they were arrays. I was just trying to decide how to edit it.